# If a bounty question is not answered/solved, why is amount not returned to asker?

Tags: discussion, bounty

My first time trying a bounty on a rather important question for me.

No one came close to offering anything in the way of a solution, and yet the bounty was not returned.

Why?

Comment: I ran an ad in the newspaper. It failed to bring me new business. Should the newspaper refund my money?

Comment: This "payment" was not to the "paper", it was meant for the person answering the question. So your comment is not applicable.

Comment: Consider the paper SO. Yes, it is most definitely applicable.

Comment: Again, who gets the bounty if answered? Does the person answering an ad in the paper get the money.? But the person below is correct...I didn't read the fine print. :)

Comment: If bounties were refunded when you didn't assign them, what would stop someone from offering a bounty then claiming none of the answers helped, just so he could get the rep back?

Comment: Not sure why this question has so many downvotes... It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque .. it is because I didn't read the fine print. I am being punished for my lack of due diligence. :) But true, it would help others not make the same mistake. But yes, there are some punitive %%%hats on this board. Witness the down vote of the other answer which was also useful. :)

Comment: see also: [The purpose of losing reputation when using a bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380598/the-purpose-of-losing-reputation-when-using-a-bounty)

Comment: I just came here because I failed to read the fine print as well.  It would be nice if the unclaimed bounty could be added on top of future bounties.  That way the bounty remains deducted from your rep and still requires additional rep cost to post future bounties but could make those more enticing.

Comment: Not refunding helps to prevent frivolous bounties.  But if a bounty expires with ZERO answers, then what is the argument for no refund?  This policy could cause someone with low reputation to hesitate to set a bounty for a valid but esoteric question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The bounty is *not* a guarantee you are getting an answer. The bounty is **advertising**. You placed an advertisement in the paper here.

As such, you get what you paid for, attention. You cannot get a refund on that.

The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is crystal clear on this:

> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can **draw attention** to your question by placing a bounty on it.
>
> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, **and is non-refundable**. If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a bounty ***may* help attract more attention** and more answers.
>
> [...]
>
> - **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**

*Emphasis mine*.

The bounty dialog box also tells you this:

<kbd>[image: bounty dialog with *cannot be refunded* circled in red]</kbd>

If the bounty was instead refunded, you could just repost the bounty, over and over, forever drawing attention to your question, and *away* from other, more answerable questions. That wouldn't be fair; you would get more attention for the same amount of reputation.

Comment: Ahh you are correct...I did not read the fine print. :)

However, I still contented that the "I placed an ad" analogy does not apply, since the "payment" goes to the person who would answer the question and NOT to the paper. :)

Comment: @E.Maggini: plenty of newspapers have used bounties to create news in the past though. The attempts to cross the channel between France and the UK by plane were entirely motivated by a newspaper bounty. Others place bounties with the newspaper ad: *1000 gold pieces to the finder of my rare breed lapdog!*. Here the service is merely combined, you get attention, and hopefuls will pitch for the bounty and see their name in lights by answering.

Answer (score 8):

I agree that the "newspaper ad" analogy is not correct.

The newspaper charges you, regardless of outcome from the ad, to pay for their costs which they have to outlay regardless of the outcome from ad. Proof reading/checking alignment etc, editorial, ink, printer, delivery, etc.

It *costs* Stack nothing (barring extra page hits, some extra database usage from storing the bounty, etc) and as such Stack doesn't actually gain anything from it either.

If the analogy was correct, Stack would reclaim the rep to cover their costs.
It's nonsense to even compare really, comparing a profit based business service to a free public service.

Rep is put up regardless of outcome for reasons entirely different to the newspaper ad charging you.

---

Anyway..

Adding to what Martijn Pieters said "Refunded bounty = *infinite free bounty* until you get an answer" means everyone (nearly) would place a bounty on their question as *there is no risk or loss involved*, and if they get an answer then it was worthwhile.

And everyone (nearly) placing a bounty would dilute bounties to the point it would be common place and so no longer a unique method to gain great attention above other questions.

Bounties have to cost you rep to make them work, regardless of the outcome, it's that simple.

But again, I don't agree it matches the newspaper ad analogy at all.
The only similarity is "doing something to get attention from people", in that logic, running around McDonald’s naked is a bounty/ad....

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer as well. :) And on a side note, anonymous down voting is lame. I can understand why it was done to me, since I should have read the fine print....In your case, it is clearly punitive and not constructive at all..

Comment: Did you try that running around *thing* ... ? If it was successful I might consider that ...

Comment: @rene Sadly the bounty was placed *on me*

Answer (score -7):

Looks to me that it's simply because the people who make these decisions, whoever they are, do not know the difference between fairness from unfairness, or to put it simply, right from wrong.

And this is just an example of several toxic Stack Overflow policies that are only detrimental and frustration-causing to everybody, including to Stack Overflow.

https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/7szv7i/anyone_else_find_the_stack_overflow_community/

I suppose the argument given above, that if bounties were refundable, people would just keep re-posting / spamming them forever is the best enthusiastic explanation for this policy.  However, at 50 points each, I still wonder if this was ever a problem.  And that brings on another question -- why then always take all of the bounty?  Why couldn't the rules be that if a bounty is not answered, say only 10% of it is taken to discourage "spamming", instead of all 100%?

It's like posting a reward for a lost pet, and having to pay it even if nobody looks for it.

The current rules make posting bounties too much of a crapshoot to be worth it.  Personally I just lost 50 rep points on an unanswered bounty, and don't have the desire to lose another 50.  And if these points don't get my bounty answered and are so easy to lose, then what's the point of amassing them anyway.

And that's too bad, because bounties could be used to encourage answers to really hard questions, that would be useful for everybody.

So my answer to this question is, that bounties are non-refundable because (1) the people who make these decisions do now know the difference between fairness and unfairness (to be polite about it).  And also because of (2) one of life's most true virtues -- No good deed goes unpunished!

And because (3) there are only two things guaranteed in life -- death and taxes.  And possibly because of (4) the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons

Another reason why is because (5) there currently does not appear to be an active alternative to this service on the Internet, so as a monopoly it does not need to try to be better.

So there you go, I just came up with no less than 5 good explanations for this misery!

Comment: Is this an answer or just a rant?

Comment: You dredged up a 5 year old thread just to rant? Why?

Comment: @Magisch I imagine out of frustration at not getting results for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48001774/timeline) bounty. The rant is completely misguided and out of place, but that's their likely motivation.

Comment: If you want to change how bounties work, I suggest writing up a clear argument with [tag:feature-request].  Please read the tag before posting, however, as it takes a respectable amount of effort to make a case for changing the system; just complaining you don't like it isn't going to cut it.

Comment: My work here is done. :)

Comment: In case you do actually create a feature-request for this, I strongly suggest you use a higher percentage than 10%. Paying only 5 points on a 50 point bounty isn't going to stop anyone from immediately placing another bounty if it doesn't get an answer. That or come up with some other mechanism for often a user puts a bounty on a question.