# unclaimed bounty: what happens to the bounty if no one answers?

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I know it is not returned to the user from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276494/1991504).

I feel all the unclaimed bounty for a current week should be either distributed to the users who commented below the question or users who claimed bounty during that time. though it will be tedious to distribute bounty is such a way but still instead of wasting it, I feel it should be invested somewhere else by the community.

Comment: The bounty will not be awarded and disappears.

Comment: The bounty **buys attention**. It is not wasted; your question will get that attention as people come looking at how they might earn it with answering.

Comment: If it were to be awarded to anyone commenting you'd be **inundated** with useless comments. This is a terrible idea.

Comment: Not just any comments, we can have moderators to validate the usefulness of a comment.

Comment: You think the moderators sit around doing nothing all day? They are **exception handlers**. Bounties are not exceptional.

Comment: I said i know it is not awarded i requested for a feature-request also linked the previous post

Comment: I know you made it a feature request, I voted accordingly.

Comment: In a day there are hardly 10-15 bounties which go off without any answers. Where as there are 10-15 questions per minute which are moderated by users. So i dont think it will be a more of hectic for them.

Comment: Bounties are there to get good answers, voted on by the community. Comments are there for clarifications, not answers. Bounties are not going to waste here. The term *moderators* without qualification implies that you are talking about the *elected diamond moderators*, not the community in general, be careful with that term; from context I think you mean the community, not moderators.

Comment: Community why whould you need diamond moderators for this.  There are suggested ways to take a different approach in comments also. There is another suggested way to distribute the unclaimed bounty to other users also.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a terrible idea.

Bounties are there to *attract attention to a question*. People post answers in the hope of claiming the bounty, but an unawarded bounty is *never wasted*. Reputation is not a zero-sum game where there is a certain amount to go around; reputation is endless and 'destroying' some makes no difference to the system.

Awarding a bounty to *comments* is going to lead to a huge waste of effort to clean up needless comments. Comments are there for clarification, not for answering, and how we moderate comments reflect this. You can only vote up comments, not down, and cleaning up comments is a little harder. Only enough flags or a diamond moderator can delete a comment.

As such anyone posting comments in the hopes of claiming the bounty is running no risk of losing reputation from downvotes. At worst their comment is deleted. But for the *question with the bounty* what will happen is that there will be **tons** of useless comments and it'll take a lot of work from diamond moderators to clean these up.

Awarding 'unclaimed' bounties to other answers that were awarded a bounty also doesn't work. Bounties are there to encourage answers on a *specific question*, and the posted amount reflects how much someone is willing to pay for it. They'll get answers accordingly. Other bounties should have no bearing on it.